# Error while processing route, adapter operation failed

Tags: ember.js

While running the below code, I got an error that adapter operation failed.

(aap.js)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store=DS.Store.extend({

adapter:'DS.FixtureAdapter' 
});
 //App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();



App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('posts');
    this.route('about');
});

App.PostsRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return this.store.find('post');
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it represents no research at all.

Answer (score 0):

`adapter:` parameter in store expected adapter name that you extended/created or adapter object, e.g. you created application adapter like `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();` so your adapter parameter should be `'application'`, but without specifying adapter in store it will default to application adapter so there is need for specifying it